# How did TIdTCPServer multicast to ALL Clients in A 60Hz timer?

Tags: delphi, tcp, real-time, c++builder, broadcast

I am a newbie working with Indy. This is my first time posting a question here.

My project has to send data to all clients at 60Hz. I am using `TIdTCPServer` for this, and to monitor keep-alives. My tool is very old, running on WinXP, using C++Builder 6 and Indy 8. There is a potential timeout issue, does anyone have a good thought how to handle it?

Here is my code:

Server Side

```cpp
typedef struct
{
    AnsiString PeerIP;     //{ Cleint IP address }
    AnsiString HostName;   //{ Hostname }
    int Id;        // {Cleint ID}
} TClient;


// This is Multimedia timer callback function, on 60Hz

void CALLBACK mmTimerProc(UINT wTimerID, UINT msg, DWORD dwUser, DWORD dw1, DWORD dw2)
{
    DWORD T1, T2;
    TfmMain *pMain = (TfmMain *)dwUser;
    int Index;
    double dT;
    TClient *pClient;

    if (pMain->IsClosing) return;


    if (pMain->Shutdown)
    {
        return;
    }


    pMain->UpdateServer1Data();

    TList *pList = pMain->IdTCPServer1->Threads->LockList();
    try
    {
        for(int X = 0; X < pList->Count; X++)
        {
            if (!pMain->IsClosing)
            {
                TIdPeerThread *AThread = (TIdPeerThread *)pList->Items[X];

                if(AThread != NULL)
                {
                    pClient = (TClient *)AThread->Data;
                    try
                    {
                        if(!AThread->Connection->ClosedGracefully)
                        {
                            // Send data to ALL Clients
                            AThread->Connection->WriteBuffer(&pMain->Data2Client, sizeof(pMain->Data2Client), true);
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception &E)
                    {
                        if(!AThread->Stopped)
                        {
                            AThread->Stop();
                            AThread->Connection->Disconnect();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    __finally
    {
        pMain->IdTCPServer1->Threads->UnlockList();
    }

    // Shutdown computer or close application

    if(pMain->SimIos.Status.iSimStatus == 11)
    {
        pMain->Shutdown = true;
        pMain->CloseApp();
    }
}


void __fastcall TfmMain::IdTCPServer1Connect(TIdPeerThread *AThread)
{
    TClient *pClient = NULL;
    AnsiString ABuffer, text;
    AnsiString PeerIP   = AThread->Connection->Binding->PeerIP;
    TDateTime TimeConnected = Now();


    ABuffer = AThread->Connection->ReadLn();
    if((ABuffer.Pos("TT") == 0) && (ABuffer.Pos("IG") == 0) && (ABuffer.Pos("RR") == 0))
    {
        text = AnsiString().sprintf("1>>> Unknown(%s) on %s connected illegal!...",
                            PeerIP, DateTimeToStr(TimeConnected));
        WriteMsg(text);
        AThread->Connection->Disconnect();
        return;
    }

    if(ABuffer.Pos("IG") != 0)
    {
        pClient = new TClient;
        pClient->PeerIP     = PeerIP;
        pClient->HostName   = Clients[eIG];
        pClient->Id         = eIG;

        AThread->Data = (TObject *)pClient;
        AThread->FreeOnTerminate = true;

        // Report client is on line
    }

    text = AnsiString().sprintf("1>>>%s(%s) on %s on line!...",
                        pClient->HostName, PeerIP, DateTimeToStr(TimeConnected));
    WriteMsg(text);    
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TfmMain::IdTCPServer1Disconnect(TIdPeerThread *AThread)
{
    TClient *pClient = NULL;
    AnsiString Msg;


    if (IsClosing) return;


    pClient = (TClient *)AThread->Data;

    if(pClient->Id == 1)
    {
        // Report client is off line
        Msg = AnsiString().sprintf("1>>>%s(%s) on %s off line...",
        pClient->HostName, pClient->PeerIP, DateTimeToStr(Now()));
        WriteMsg(Msg);
    }


    delete pClient;
    AThread->Data = NULL;
    AThread->Terminate();

    try
    {
        IdTCPServer1->Threads->LockList()->Remove(AThread);
    }
    __finally
    {
        IdTCPServer1->Threads->UnlockList();
    }

}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TfmMain::IdTCPServer1Execute(TIdPeerThread *AThread)
{
    TClient *pClient;


    if (!AThread->Terminated && !IsClosing)
    {
        pClient = (TClient *)AThread->Data;
        if((pClient != NULL) && (pClient->Id != 0))
        {
            try
            {
                if(pClient->Id == 1)
                {
                    // Report client still alive
                }
            }
            catch(Exception &E)
            {
                if (!IsClosing)
                {
                    if(!AThread->Stopped)
                    {
                        AThread->Stop();
                        AThread->Connection->Disconnect();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Client side

```cpp
void __fastcall TSocketThread::Execute()
{
    unsigned long ulCheckSum;
    SIM_SVR1_ACK_STRUCT   Ack2Svr;
    SIM_SVR_DATA   DataFromSvr;
    int Counter;


    memset(&DataFromSvr, 0, sizeof(DataFromSvr));
    memset(&Ack2Svr,  0, sizeof(Ack2Svr));
    Counter = 0;

    // fetch and process commands until the connection or thread is terminated
    while (!this->Terminated && FSocket->Connected())
    {
        try
        {
            // recieve data from server
            FSocket->ReadBuffer(&DataFromSvr, sizeof(DataFromSvr));

            // check CRC
            ulCheckSum = CRC_32((unsigned char*)&DataFromSvr.SimData, sizeof(DataFromSvr.SimData));

            if (ulCheckSum == DataFromSvr.uiCheckSum)
            {
                FSmIpcUtil->Writeto(&DataFromSvr.SimData, DATA_OFFSET, sizeof(DataFromSvr.SimData));
            }

            else
            {
                // counter to record error  
                Synchronize(UpdateCaption);
            }

            // read return from local SM
            FSmIpcUtil->Readfrom(&Ack2Svr, ACK_OFFSET, sizeof(Ack2Svr));

            FSocket->WriteBuffer(&Ack2Svr, sizeof(Ack2Svr));

            if (DataFromSvr.SimData.SimIgTgt.Acdata.iSimStatus == 11)
            {
                Terminate();
                FSocket->Disconnect();

                PostMessage(Application->Handle, WM_SHUTDOWN, 0, 0);

                Sleep(500);
            }
        }

        catch (EIdException& E)
        {
            this->Terminate();
            FSocket->Disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues with your code.

A multimedia timer callback is very restricted in what it is allowed to do:

> Applications should not call any system-defined functions from inside a callback function, **except for** `PostMessage`, `timeGetSystemTime`, `timeGetTime`, `timeSetEvent`, `timeKillEvent`, `midiOutShortMsg`, `midiOutLongMsg`, and `OutputDebugString`.

If transmission speed is important, don't have the timer callback do the broadcasting at all.  Save the data somewhere safe, and then have each `TIdTCPServer` thread grab the latest data on its own time.  This also keeps each connection thread isolated so one connection cannot affect any other connection if problems occur.

DO NOT set the `TIdPeerThread::FreeOnTerminate` to true, DO NOT call `TIdPeerThread::Stop()`, DO NOT manually remove threads from the `TIdTCPServer::Threads` property.  You do not own the threads, `TIdTCPServer` does, and it will manage them for you.  If you want to stop a given thread, closing the thread's socket is all you need to do.  But by moving all of the sending logic into `OnExecute` where it belongs, you can let `TIdTCPServer` handle any errors and close the socket for you.

Your `OnConnect` event handler is setting `AThread->Data` only if an IG client connects, but your `OnConnect` and `OnDisconnect` handlers are not checking for that condition before attempting to access the `TClient` object.

Your `OnDisconnect` event handler is leaking memory if `IsClosing` is true.  And it is calling `Threads->UnlockList()` without calling `Threads->LockList()` first.  Attempting to unlock the list when it is not locked by the calling thread will cause errors and deadlocks.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
struct TClient
{
    AnsiString PeerIP;     //{ Client IP address }
    AnsiString HostName;   //{ Hostname }
    int Id;                //{ Client ID }
};

void CALLBACK mmTimerProc(UINT wTimerID, UINT msg, DWORD dwUser, DWORD dw1, DWORD dw2)
{
    TfmMain *pMain = (TfmMain *)dwUser;

    if (pMain->IsClosing || pMain->Shutdown) return;

    pMain->UpdateServer1Data();    
    // make sure pMain->Data2Client is thread-safe...
    // set a signal that Data2Client has been updated...

    // Shutdown computer or close application

    if (pMain->SimIos.Status.iSimStatus == 11)
    {
        pMain->Shutdown = true;
        pMain->CloseApp();
    }
}

void __fastcall TfmMain::IdTCPServer1Connect(TIdPeerThread *AThread)
{
    TClient *pClient;
    AnsiString ABuffer, text;
    AnsiString PeerIP = AThread->Connection->Binding->PeerIP;
    TDateTime TimeConnected = Now();

    ABuffer = AThread->Connection->ReadLn();
    if ((ABuffer.Pos("TT") == 0) && (ABuffer.Pos("IG") == 0) && (ABuffer.Pos("RR") == 0))
    {
        text = AnsiString().sprintf("1>>> Unknown(%s) on %s connected illegal!...", PeerIP.c_str(), DateTimeToStr(TimeConnected).c_str());
        WriteMsg(text);
        AThread->Connection->Disconnect();
        return;
    }

    pClient = new TClient;
    pClient->PeerIP = PeerIP;

    if (ABuffer.Pos("IG") != 0)
    {
        pClient->HostName   = Clients[eIG];
        pClient->Id         = eIG;
    }
    else
        pClient->Id         = 0;

    AThread->Data = (TObject *)pClient;

    // Report client is on line

    text = AnsiString().sprintf("1>>>%s(%s) on %s on line!...", pClient->HostName.c_str(), PeerIP.c_str(), DateTimeToStr(TimeConnected).c_str());
    WriteMsg(text);    
}

void __fastcall TfmMain::IdTCPServer1Disconnect(TIdPeerThread *AThread)
{
    TClient *pClient = (TClient *)AThread->Data;
    AnsiString Msg;

    AThread->Data = NULL;

    if (pClient)
    {
        // Report client is off line
        Msg = AnsiString().sprintf("1>>>%s(%s) on %s off line...",
            pClient->HostName.c_str(), pClient->PeerIP.c_str(), DateTimeToStr(Now()).c_str());
        WriteMsg(Msg);

        delete pClient;
    }
}

void __fastcall TfmMain::IdTCPServer1Execute(TIdPeerThread *AThread)
{
    TClient *pClient;

    if (IsClosing) return;

    // make sure pMain->Data2Client is thread-safe...
    if (Data2Client has been updated since last event)
    {
        AThread->Connection->WriteBuffer(&pMain->Data2Client, sizeof(pMain->Data2Client), true);
    }

    pClient = (TClient *)AThread->Data;
    // Report client still alive
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sorry for lately responded.

Comment: Thank you Remy. Sorry for lately responded. Pointed me the memory leak issue. I would watch it. I had some quiestion. First I did not see the periodic event to send data to ALL clients from your suggestion. The timer callback function only update data periodically. How to make sure server sent same data to each client? Second, I used CriticalSection in UpdateServer1Data function, is it safe? How did I set "(Data2Client has been updated since last event)" correctly? (I would put my client's code in question.)

Comment: @BeezWeng if it is important that each and every timer event sends data to all clients, then you can't avoid looping through the clients on every timer event. But I do not recommend doing the actual sending inside the timer event directly.

Comment: @BeezWeng One way is to give each client its own thread-safe queue of data, have the timer push data into each client's queue, and have each client's `OnExecute` send its particular client's queue. Another way is to have the timer push data into a single thread-safe queue, and have another dedicated thread send that queue to each client, and have the timer wait until the queue is emptied before exiting.

Comment: It is positive that each and every timer event sends data to all clients. Could you give some sample code to figure out "each client its own thread-safe queue of data" and "push data into a single thread-safe queue"? By the way, how about SetEvent in timer when timer updated data completely? Thanks.

Comment: Followed your lead, I created a thread to wait for timer to set event, then sent data to clients. It work fine. No more deadlock and closed smoothly. Thanks.